# angular 5 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Service

Tags: angular5

I could use a little help.

Context I am making a angular 5 module for an authentication service.

How do I pass a POJO into a class as parameters?

See my answer below.

<strike>I need to use HttpClient inside this auth service</strike>

I am getting this error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthService: ([object Object], ?).

[object Object] is angular 5 HttpClient

Can some one please explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

```
@NgModule()

export class AuthtModule {
  static forRoot(params?: iParams) {
    return {
        ngModule: AuthModule,
        provides: [
            HttpClient,
            {
                provide: AuthService,
                useFactory: setupAuthService,
                deps: [ HttpClient, params ]
            }
        ],
        imports: [ HttpClientModule ],
        exports: [ AuthService ]            

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, as it turns out the problem was with the second parameter (hence the question mark) not the first. the reason this error occurs is because in order for parameters to be passed into a class they must first be turned into a injectable.

Here is how you do it.

First create a class model with the params

foo-params.model.ts

```
export class FooParams {
  public foo1: string;
  public foo2: number;
}
```

Then In the Module class attributes set the class FooParams to use the values that are a POJO

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FooParams } from './foo-params';

@NgModule({
  imports : [ HttpClientModule ],
  providers: [{
   HttpClient
   { provider: FooParams, useValue: params },
   { 
     provider: BarService,
     useFactory: setupBarService
     deps: [ HttpClient, FooParams ]
   }
  }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this is what the class that consumes the pojo would look like.
bar.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FooParams } from './foo.service.ts';

expecto function setupBarService(http: HttpClient, params: FooParams) {
  return new BarService(http, params);
}

@Injectable()
export class BarService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, params: FooParams) {}

  //DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by importing `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` in polyfills.ts